# creating open source online game

Tags: open-source, online-game

I started creating online open source game as a project in school. It will be server with n connected clients. But now I have a problem with "security". What to do if one client would used modified source code for changing some restrictions? How can I prevent it? My first idea was make client only for connection to server and server would send all necessary files but I don't like this idea very much. Can you advise me something better? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep your validations in the server. The server should check each client move, and if it's not allowed according to the server's rules - reject it.

You should still keep validations in the client, too, so that users who don't mess with the client code can get speedier responses.

Comment: Beat me to it by 30s. It might be interesting to know that this is exactly what Freeciv does to prevent users from cheating with modified versions of the game.

Comment: That's what *every* web application should do, game or not a game.